# Error while booting PC: pciehp: Cannot get irq -1 for the hotplug controller

Tags: boot, hotplug

I've installed Ubuntu on a new PC with GigaByte mother board, SSD and HDD disks.
After installation, when I boot the system I'm getting the following two lines of error:

pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: pciehp: Notification initialization failed (-1)
pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: pciehp: Cannot get irq -1 for the hotplug controller

Could you please help me to find where the problem is and how to solve it?

Comment: You can ignore this message if the system boots OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of my poor knowledge of the subject, I thought version 22.10 was stable. I solved the problem by installing the Ubuntu version 22.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0):

What helped me to get rid of that message is to add kernel parameter `pciehp pciehp_poll_mode=1`.

I've added it to `/etc/default/grub` at the end of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` and run `sudo update-grub`

Ref: https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000016874

Answer (score 0):

got this problem on my new rig (GIGABYTE z790 AD, RX 7900xtx, i5 13600K).

Fixed it by using amdgpu-install (https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

I know you have fixed your problem but I thought I would put this here since It's the first result pop up in my search engine for this problem